# Como selecionar dados de tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql

Como fazer um `select` pegando um campo de cada tabela?

Quero pegar o campo texto de 4 tabelas diferentes, como deveria fazer?

Comment: Poderia colocar as tabelas e explicar o objetivo da consulta

Comment: @Felipe - No select,vc precisa indicar de qual tabela é o campo e no from você vai casando as tabelas.  Edita seu post e coloca as tabelas que fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que voce deseja:

**tabelas:**

```
TB_USUARIO  |   TB_ENDERECO         | TB_CEP        | TB_CIDADE
------------|-----------------------|---------------|-----------
ID_USUARIO  |   ID_ENDERECO         | ID_CEP        | ID_CIDADE
NOME        |   ID_USUARIO          | ID_ENDERECO   | ID_CEP
                ENDERECO            | CEP           | CIDADE
```

**Método 1:**

```
SELECT 
    TB_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO,
    TB_USUARIO.NOME,
    TB_ENDERECO.ID_ENDERECO,
    TB_ENDERECO.ID_USUARIO,
    TB_ENDERECO.ENDERECO,
    TB_CEP.ID_CEP,
    TB_CEP.ID_ENDERECO,
    TB_CEP.CEP,
    TB_CIDADE.ID_CIDADE,
    TB_CIDADE.ID_CEP,
    TB_CIDADE.CIDADE
    FROM TB_USUARIO
    INNER JOIN TB_ENDERECO 
    ON TB_ENDERECO.ID_USUARIO = TB_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO
    INNER JOIN TB_CEP
    ON TB_CEP.ID_ENDERECO = TB_ENDERECO.ID_ENDERECO
    INNER JOIN TB_CIDADE
    ON TB_CIDADE.ID_CEP = TB_CEP.ID_CEP
```

**Método 2: Adicionando apelido às tabelas:**

```
SELECT 
    usu.ID_USUARIO,
    usu.NOME,
    en.ID_ENDERECO,
    en.ID_USUARIO,
    en.ENDERECO,
    cep.ID_CEP,
    cep.ID_ENDERECO,
    cep.CEP,
    cid.ID_CIDADE,
    cid.ID_CEP,
    cid.CIDADE
    FROM TB_USUARIO usu
    INNER JOIN TB_ENDERECO en ON (end.ID_USUARIO = usu.ID_USUARIO)
    INNER JOIN TB_CEP cep ON (cep.ID_ENDERECO = en.ID_ENDERECO)
    INNER JOIN TB_CIDADE cid ON (cid.ID_CEP = cep.ID_CEP)
```

**Método 3: Retornando todos os campos das tabelas:**

```
SELECT * FROM TB_USUARIO usu
    INNER JOIN TB_ENDERECO end ON (end.ID_USUARIO = usu.ID_USUARIO)
    INNER JOIN TB_CEP cep ON (TB_CEP.ID_ENDERECO = end.ID_ENDERECO)
    INNER JOIN TB_CIDADE cid ON (TB_CIDADE.ID_CEP = TB_CEP.ID_CEP)
```

Estes são exemplos de como pode ser feito, existe vários outros!

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, estava em duvida de como fazer!

Answer (score 4):

Pode ser feito dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT a.name, b.term_taxonomy_id 
    FROM wp_terms a, wp_term_taxonomy b 
    WHERE a.term_id=b.term_id
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, ficou melhor a visualização.